# Java - ArrayList / Array

Tags: java

I have two array lists `namesArrayList1` and `namesArrayList2`, each contains values.

my question is how to put the two Array Lists in one array `allNames[]`?

Comment: have you tried anything yet?

Comment: nope still searching for an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a new list from existing list 1

```
List<String> allList = new ArrayList<>(namesArrayList1)
```

Add all others

```
allList.addAll(namesArrayList2);
```

Convert to array

```
String[] allArray = allList.toArray(new String[]{});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use [`System.arraycopy()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29):

```
String[] allNames = new String[namesArrayList1.size() + namesArrayList2.size()];
System.arraycopy(namesArrayList1.toArray(), 0, allNames, 0, namesArrayList1.size());  
System.arraycopy(namesArrayList2.toArray(), 0, allNames, namesArrayList1.size(), namesArrayList2.size());
```

---

**Example:**

```
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
list1.add("aa");
list1.add("bb");
list1.add("cc");
list1.add("dd");
List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
list2.add("ee");
list2.add("ff");
list2.add("gg");
list2.add("jj");

String[] allNames = new String[list1.size() + list1.size()];
System.arraycopy(list1.toArray(), 0, allNames, 0, list1.size());  
System.arraycopy(list2.toArray(), 0, allNames, list1.size(), list2.size());

for (String all : allNames) {
    System.out.print(all+ " ");
}
```

**Output:**

```
aa bb cc dd ee ff gg jj
```

Answer (score -1):

I found a one-line solution from the good old Apache Commons Lang library.

```
ArrayUtils.addAll(T[], T...)
```

Code:

```
String[] both = (String[])ArrayUtils.addAll(first, second);
```

or you can use this code

```
int[] array1and2 = new int[namesArrayList1.length + namesArrayList2.length];
System.arraycopy(namesArrayList1, 0, array1and2, 0, namesArrayList1.length);
System.arraycopy(namesArrayList2, 0, array1and2, namesArrayList1.length, namesArrayList2.length);
```

This will work regardless of the size of namesArrayList1 and namesArrayList2.